# Is this undefined behavior

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer

From my understanding, this program should have undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 3, b = 3, c = 10, d = 20;
   int e = (a++ * ++b)-((c / b) * a) + d;
   printf("%d", e)  ;

   return 0;
}
```

> The C99 standard §6.5 ¶2 says
>
> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value
>   to be stored.

So, in the line defining `'e'`, `a` and `b` are being read not only for determining what to store back in `a` and `b`, but also to compute the expression `((c / b) * a)`

However, gcc does not give warning even with `-Wsequence-point warning`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `gcc --version` is always a good idea with such questions.

Comment: @rici: https://ideone.com/NbV30F. That is gcc 8.3

Comment: Might be a problem with ideone, or it's not using the warning options you think it is.  The Godbolt [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8Z8vNx) shows warnings as expected, as does my local gcc 9.2.1.

Comment: @nate So does tio.run: (gcc 8.3.1) https://tio.run/##NYzLDoIwEEX3/YobjElrqaIuUX/DdZkWbIIFeayMv24dNK5OzuTcIdMQpbQKkdrZeZzGyYVue7sIEeKEuw1RKvEUABa3OOOYo/qBGPsih2MeivIfeVZptcYGWlfKSEnYoVLsVkHDfct@4LaW2dplObwCSrGcBz/NQwR/e6X0prq1zZjMdfSP2Ufypu949gE

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ok. Thanks for that note. Yes, indeed, as suspected, this is a sequence point warning

Comment: Thanks @rici. Should have checked one of these apart from ideone. Thanks for your help

Comment: I tested with GCC versions 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 8.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.3.0, 9.1.0 and 9.2.0, and each one reported `-Werror=sequence-point` (error because I also used `-Werror`).  This was tested on a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.  I built the compilers between November 2017 and August 2019, so they were not all built on Mojave.

Comment: GCC version 4.7.1 properly reports `[-Wsequence-point]` for both `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiled with clang compiler (version - clang-1001.0.46.4), getting these warnings:

```
   p.c:6:19: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'b' [-Wunsequenced]
       int e = (a++ * ++b)-((c / b) * a) + d;
                        ^        ~
   p.c:6:14: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
       int e = (a++ * ++b)-((c / b) * a) + d;
                ^                     ~
```

From C11 Standards#6.5p2 *[emphasis added]*

> 2 **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to** either a different side effect on the same scalar object or **a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined**. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.84)

The expression invokes undefined behaviour.

---

**Edit:**

The question tagged with `gcc`, so for the completeness of answer below is the output when compiled with `gcc` compiler with `-Wall` option:

```
p.c:6:19: warning: operation on 'b' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
    int e = (a++ * ++b)-((c / b) * a) + d;
                   ^
p.c:6:14: warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
    int e = (a++ * ++b)-((c / b) * a) + d;
              ^
```

Note that, if we do not specify any options (like `-Wall` or `-Wsequence-point`) to `gcc` while compiling, it's not giving any warning message on the expression in question but that's not the case with `clang` compiler.